# Subset dataframe based on multiple like conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe-

```
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     NaN   12
2  Clarke   13
3    Lexy   14
4   Marie   10
```

I need to subset the dataframe based on `Name` column. I want to only keep rows having name like `%lex%` or `%clarke%` or `%bob%` (case-insensitive). I have tried [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [df.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) but it's way too long. Is there a better way to do this?

What I've tried so far-

```
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('lex', na=False, case=False) | df['Name'].str.contains('clarke', na=False, case=False)]
df.query('Name.str.contains("lex", na=False, case=False) or Name.str.contains("clarke", na=False, case=False)', engine='python')
```

Minimum reproducible code-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['Alex', 10], [np.nan, 12], ['Clarke', 13], ['Lexy', 14], ['Marie', 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
```

Expected output-

```
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
2  Clarke   13
3    Lexy   14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do

```
out = df[df['Name'].str.contains('lex|clarke', na=False, case=False)]
Out[5]: 
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
2  Clarke   13
3    Lexy   14
```